# iOS - Add Badge to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How do I add a badge to `UITableViewCell`, like this:

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/9974/img0001ac9.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/9974/img0001ac9.png)

Should I simply add a subview with a text and label on it?

Comment: [Here](http://www.spaulus.com/2010/09/create-a-custom-iphone-ipad-badge/?lang=en) is an alternativ of my own. Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a swift enhancement to @POF's answer. We don't need as many subviews and we can use math to support N digits, not just 1-3:

```
func setDiscountBadge(count: Int) {
  let size: CGFloat = 26
  let digits = CGFloat( count("\(number)") ) // digits in the label
  let width = max(size, 0.7 * size * digits) // perfect circle is smallest allowed
  let badge = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, size))
  badge.text = "\(number)"
  badge.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2
  badge.layer.masksToBounds = true
  badge.textAlignment = .Center
  badge.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  badge.backgroundColor = cfg.UIColors.brand
  YOURCELL.accessoryView = badge // !! change this line
}
```

And the result (I use a brand color, but yours can be any color):

[image: uilabel badge]

Answer (score 2):

As for me **the simplest** way is to use `cell.accessoryView`. Please look into my code how I did it:

```
UIImageView * commentsViewBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"counter1.png"]];
commentsViewBG.frame = CGRectMake(
    commentsViewBG.frame.origin.x,
    commentsViewBG.frame.origin.y, 30, 20);


UILabel *commentsCount;
if (commentsArray.totalCount < 10)
    commentsCount = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, -10, 40, 40)];
else if (commentsArray.totalCount < 100)
    commentsCount = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, -10, 40, 40)];
else if (commentsArray.totalCount < 1000)
{
    commentsViewBG.frame = CGRectMake(
        commentsViewBG.frame.origin.x,
        commentsViewBG.frame.origin.y, 40, 20);
    commentsCount = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, -10, 40, 40)];
}
commentsCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)commentsArray.totalCount];
commentsCount.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
commentsCount.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[commentsViewBG addSubview:commentsCount];
cell.accessoryView = commentsViewBG;
```

**And my result:**

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't post the exact same answer to multiple questions: it's either not a good fit for all or the questions are duplicates which should be flagged/closed as such.

Comment: If it makes it easier to find, I don't see much problem. Sometimes duplicate questions show up first on Google, and even if they are flagged, they can sometimes have better answers.

Answer (score 2):

[TDBadgedCell](https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell) is a pretty good choice. Highly customizable for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is currently no supported way of adding a badge to a UITableView Cell. In this example, it is most likely a custom subview which contains an image and UILabel.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add another alternative to create customized Badges. [CustomBadge](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge) is a little bit more powerful. It's open and for free.